# Fixed or random effects in a subgroup analysis where heterogeneity is present in one of the subgroups but not the overall pooled result?

Tags: random-effects-model, meta-analysis, fixed-effects-model, heterogeneity

I am looking at a meta-analysis where a subgroup analysis has been performed, as it is important to consider the treatment effect within 2 subgroups of interest, as well as the overall pooled result.

Little heterogeneity was detected in the overall pooled result (I2=32%), but when the studies are subgrouped, there is substantial heterogeneity in one of the subgroups (I2=66%) and no heterogeneity in the other subgroup (I2=0%).

In the protocol the authors said they would use random effects when moderate heterogeneity was observed (I2>40%). Currently they have performed the analysis using fixed-effects, but should I recommend they switch to random-effects so that the treatment effect in the subgroup with substantial heterogeneity is appropriately estimated?

Comment: Are you serving as a referee for the stated study?

Comment: My typical approach is to report both fixed and random effect results, and if they are discrepant consider the findings hypothesis generating but not conclusive.